# 3D control-flow graphs in IDA

Tags: disassembly, ida

Is there any way to leave 2D flow chart graphs and go to 3D model?
I mean something like that:

Usual 2D graph:
[image: 2D graph]

3D graph:
[image: 3D graph]

The only one solution I've seen is using UbiGraph + Linux on VM (to use UbiGraph) + some X-server for Win (the process of making all that stuff to work is described at Cr4sh's blog). That's kinda perverted solution, up to me.

Also it would be brilliant if there could be displayed disasm in nodes, like in ordinary 2D IDA graphs.

Perhaps there are some more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, IDA generates graphs in GDL (WinGraph) format, but you can switch it to DOT which is supported by GraphViz and some other tools. It seems [Gephi](http://gephi.org/2010/new-graphviz-dot-csv-and-ucinet-formats/) can do 3D.

See `GRAPH_FORMAT` and `GRAPH_VISUALIZER` in `ida.cfg`.